# Is it possible to use G1ANT Studio to automate outlook?

Tags: robotics, rpa, g1ant

Greetings fellow software engineers,

I've extremely new to RPA and I'm looking forward to using some of the best tools. The first task that I want to robotize/automate involves heavy use of outlook. I've seen that G1ANT gives the biggest opportunities to use programming languages (C#) and I want to know is it possible to use it to outlook automation or is there any templates/solutions to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@NeedHelpAsap, G1ANT offers a number of commands for working with Outlook. If you have already installed the latest G1ANT developer version, open it and look on the left side of the workspace for the "Addons" window (if you don't see it, go to the "View" menu at the top and click on "Addons". You should see this, or similar:

[image: Addon window]

Check the "msoffice" box as shown. You'll see a list of commands in the window below. The Outlook-related commands portion should look very much like this:

[image: List of commands]

Double-clicking any of these commands will bring up its help. In the help, in addition to a description of the command and its arguments, there is a tab for the Manual page for that command. You can also view the [G1ANT.Robot Manual page](https://manual.g1ant.com/) online.

Hope this gets you started.

Regards,
burque505

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use G1ANT studio to automate outlook, not only outlook you can automate word and many msoffice tools.
Steps to be followed automate outlook is :

1. Click on View and click on the addons
2. It will display many addons in that click the tick box of msoffice, this activates the msoffice commands and generates the
   list of commands in the down bar.
3. You can observe commands like excel,word,outlook then go to the outlook command and see the manual to workout with the outlook.

https://manual.g1ant.com/ you can follow this link, it has many more addons and commands.